# Dart - Class 'TimeOfDay' has no instance method 'toJson'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying the following:

```
json.encode(myObject);
```

But it doesn't work because `myObject` contains a property `TimeOfDay`

> Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class
>   'TimeOfDay' has no instance method 'toJson'. Receiver: Instance of
>   'TimeOfDay' Tried calling: toJson())

How can I encode an object with a property `TimeOfDay` ?

Answer (score 0):

[TimeOfDay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay-class.html) has no method called toJson,

unless you create it
else change it to n* attributes to fulfill your needs ;)